# "react - native link error File C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\react-native.ps1 cannot be loaded"

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0

Error message:

```
react-native : File C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\react-native.ps1 cannot be loaded. The
file C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\react-native.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run
this script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and setting
execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ react-native link
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

How can I solve this? I have installed npm, Node.js and JDK. I have done the tutorial for [Okta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okta_(company)#Products) authentication and in the step of react-native link I get this error.

Comment: Can you link to the Okta tutorial? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69263272/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 11):

Try setting your execution policy in PowerShell to remote
signed.

Open a new PowerShell administrator window and run `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`.

There’s also a way to allow running PowerShell scripts on Windows in Settings somewhere, but I don’t remember where. Probably in Developer Settings.

Comment: (node:7064) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports 
inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created) 

How about this?

Comment: That shouldn’t actually be keeping the command from succeeded since it’s just a warning. Reading your issue again though, react-native link command isn’t required in newer versions of react native. The instructions you are following may be a bit out of date.

Comment: Superficially there is no connection between PowerShell and React Native, but it is the file extension "`.ps1`" (PowerShell script) and "`C:\Users\ `" (Windows) that gives it away (in `File C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\react-native.ps1`"). Perhaps make it clearer in your answer that there is a connection? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 4):

*Nothing to worry about this just run PowerShell as admin and run command below in that*

**steps**

1. Go to Start Menu
2. Type PowerShell
3. Right Click PowerShell and run as
   administrator
4. And Run `set-executionpolicy remotesigne` in
   PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

Right Click PowerShell and run as administrator
And Run `set-executionpolicy remotesigne` in PowerShell
it worked for me.